# disable docker config.json credentials for google cloud registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-registry

I use Google Cloud Registry, which adds "auths" and "credHelpers" keys to my `~/.docker/config.json`.

The problem I have is that when I'm offline, or just building locally, it tries to connect to each hostname, which either fails (when offline) or is really slow (when online).

How can I tell `docker-compose` to not use these credentials/hosts when building?

My workaround now is to delete the properties from the `~/.docker/config.json`, and then `gcloud auth configure-docker` each time, but I'd rather not have to keep authenticating to push when I *do* want to use GCR.

```
ocker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://asia.gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://eu.gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://marketplace.gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://staging-k8s.gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://us.gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'gcr.io'
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'us.gcr.io'
```